# Why my recyclerView doesn't display the new data after the adapter notify data is changed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter, android-recyclerview

In the parent activity, I have an edit text in a toolbar, and user can make a search through the data displayed by the recyclerview.
When the user push enter key down, the string in the edittext is sent to the fragment by :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString(predResult, placeid);
                                    MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
                                    ListRestFragment listRestFragment = new ListRestFragment();
                                    mapFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                    listRestFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                            .replace(R.id.map, mapFragment)
                                            .replace(R.id.list_frag, listRestFragment)
                                            .commit();
```

but, unfortunatly, the recyclerview is not resfreshed while my adapter is notified the data is changed as it shown below:

```
 private void queryToList(Query query) {

        query.addSnapshotListener((queryDocumentSnapshots, e) -> {
            restaurantList = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(Restaurant.class);
            if (!myPrediction.contains("myPrediction")) {
                System.out.println(myPrediction);
                for (Restaurant item : restaurantList) {
                    if (item.getRestaurantID().contains(myPrediction)) {
                        restaurantListPred = new ArrayList<>();
                        restaurantListPred.add(item);
                        updateUI(restaurantListPred);
                    }
                }

            } else updateUI(restaurantList);
        });

    }

    private void updateUI(List<Restaurant> restaurants) {
        configureFab();
        configureRecyclerView(restaurants);
    }

    private void configureRecyclerView(List<Restaurant> restaurant) {

        this.adapter = new RestaurantAdapterClassic(restaurant);
        this.recyclerView.setAdapter(this.adapter);
        this.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleItemDecorator(getContext()));
    }
```

the new List is updated automatically when the user makes his request, but the recyclerView doesn't display the new data.

if you want to check my adapter implementation:

```
public class RestaurantAdapterClassic extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurantViewHolder> {

    private List<Restaurant> restaurantsList;

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public RestaurantAdapterClassic(List<Restaurant> restaurants) {
        this.restaurantsList = restaurants;
    }

    @Override
    public RestaurantViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        // CREATE VIEW HOLDER AND INFLATING ITS XML LAYOUT
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_pattern, parent, false);

        return new RestaurantViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RestaurantViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.updateWithRestaurant(this.restaurantsList.get(position));
    }

    // RETURN THE TOTAL COUNT OF ITEMS IN THE LIST
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.restaurantsList.size();
    }

    public Restaurant getRestaurant(int position) {
        return this.restaurantsList.get(position);
    }

    public void filterList(List<Restaurant> filteredList) {
        restaurantsList = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

where is my error or my misunderstanding?

EDIT SOLUTION -

1. Create an Interface
   Actually, to send the new data data from my Parent Activity to my Fragment with a listener to observe when the data changes.
2. Keep The data reference sent to the adapter

Actually, the main big problem that I had was my adapter doesn't refresh when I sent new array. The reason was an adapter creates a reference with the list/array. if you want to refresh it, you need to keep this reference by get the list, erase it, and put/add new data inside by the method addALL for example.

Comment: I don't see you where you call the `filterList` method

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen in this version, I didn't use it, I create a new List to display it

Comment: If you don't use it, that mean `notifyDataSetChanged()` is never called. How data can be updated to the view?

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen as he said Md. Asaduzzaman : First of all, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); doesn't have any effect in the code as inside updateUI you create the adapter every time you call it.

Comment: So what is your problem? Data is not displayed at the first time, or the RecyclerView is not updated when data changed?

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen, He creates adapter every time and attach it to recycler view. So, `notifyDataSetChanged` doesn’t have any impact .

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I don't think that is a good implementation

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen yes, when the List changed, the recyclerView doesn't show the new list.

Comment: @AlexKTP Can you explain why do you need to re-create adapter instead of updating data on existing adapter?

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen actually, I don't need to re-create a new adapter. I just want to display the new data

Comment: Yes, that it true I know that. But I think that is different things. Its not related to the issue he raised.

Comment: You should call you `updateUI` method only one, maybe in `onCreate` event. Then when you receive new data (from `addSnapshotListener`), just call `adapter. filterList(newData)`, it'll be updated on the view

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen so, you want to tell me , i should all others methods before OnResume? because  my FirestoreQuery is created in OnResume

Comment: Yes, you should setup the recyclerView before getting data

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen unfortunately still not display the new data

Comment: Is `filterList` method called while you debugging?

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen yes called, and did its jobs good. My List have juste 1 item inside after this call.

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen ok, I have find the problem. actually, it is the layout which contains my recyclerview.

Comment: Great to hear that. You should update the question and answer to help others have the same issue with you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` doesn't have any effect in the code as inside `updateUI` you create the adapter every time you call it.

I think, the main problem is in here:

```
if (item.getRestaurantID().contains(myPrediction)) {
    restaurantListPred = new ArrayList<>();
    restaurantListPred.add(item);
    updateUI(restaurantListPred);
}
```

This block doesn’t execute at all. Thats why the list not updated.

Comment: thanks for your remarks. But actually, that is the purpose, if the user makes a request, I want only one item in my new List.

Comment: Did you check by debugging or placing log inside updateUI to check whether it gets item to update RecyclerView?

Comment: yes, in the UpdateUI, after the user makes his request, the item is the good one (I have checked by placing log inside it)

Comment: Please also add your adapter implementation

Comment: In my open eyes, I couldn’t find any problem to create adapter. Let me clear again your problem, Is  your **RecyclerView doesn’t shows any data**? or **it’s not updated**?

Comment: Tell me what is `myPrediction` and  `if (item.getRestaurantID().contains(myPrediction))` logic is right?

Comment: myPrediction is a google Place ID (a string) and in every Document in my firestore collection have a field restaurantID which corresponds to their respective googlePlaceID. So I check if the list have an item with the field == to my string sent from my activity to display it in the recyclerview

Comment: Then you should use `if (item.getRestaurantID().equalsIgnoreCase(myPrediction))` isn’t it?. My assumption says that your problem is in here. Debug the code and check

Comment: Or if your `myPrediction` contains more than one places then your logic should be `if (myPrediction.contains(item.getRestaurantID()))`

Comment: I get the good restaurant to display, but still not displayed by the recyclerview

Comment: myPrediction cannot hae more than one place. It's only one Place ID.

Comment: Please debug and check your logic. Thanks

Comment: ok,thanks for your time. I have check everything. I have check maybe 100 implementation of these kinds of recycler and to be honest, i cannot see where i did wrong